# NumPy taking in data from multiple files

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble with trying to slice incoming data from multiple csv files

I have five csv files with several columns of data in each.

What I'm trying to do is look at these five files, and take the date data column (skipping the first row which are strings) from each file, and then put those columns alongside each other in an array. So given 5 files, we'll have an array with several rows and 5 columns.

```
def import_dates() :

    CA = pd.read_csv('CA.csv') #These are all reading in fine

    NY = pd.read_csv("NY.csv")

    MN = pd.read_csv("MN.csv")

    TN = pd.read_csv('TN.csv')

    FL = pd.read_csv('FL.csv')
   


    CA_time = np.array(CA[1:, 1], dtype = "datetime64") #Wheels come off here 
    NY_time = np.array(NY[1:, 1], dtype = "datetime64")
    MN_time = np.array(MN[1:, 1], dtype = "datetime64")
    TN_time = np.array(TN[1:, 1], dtype = "datetime64")
    FL_time = np.array(FL[1:, 1], dtype = "datetime64")

    
    date_series = np.array([[CA_time], [NY_time], [MN_time], [TN_time], [FL_time]])

    return date_series
```

Error I'm getting is `TypeError: '(slice(1, None, None), 1)' is an invalid key`

CSV files are formatted correctly for "datetime64" (I've used other code on it for time date type and read in fine)

Just not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help appreciated

Comment: can you provide the first few lines of at least two of the files?

Comment: pandas slicing syntax is slightly different than numpy - it also supports label-based slicing.

Comment: maybe something like this would work: `CA_time = CA["date"].astype("datetime64")`, ... `date_series = pd.concat([CA_time, NY_time, ...])`

Comment: at least to not get the current error, you need iloc like `CA.iloc[1:, 1]` (same for the others)

Comment: Looks like you need to study some more `pandas` to get the indexing right.  Otherwise, consider `arr=CA.to_numpy()` to get a numpy array from the dataframe.  But column dtypes may be a significant issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, just tried the iloc method suggested by Ben T. It worked! At least in getting the data grouped. I then used `transpose` to get it into the respective columns. I still don't fully understand how iloc made it happen though. Just getting into NumPy and pandas so want to understand conceptually whats going on.